# Combining search movement with yank

Tags: vim

`y/` or `y?` to `yank` till a specific search hit is a productivity boost that I rely on frequently but there's something that's been bothering me for a while and my searches in docs and the web haven't yielded an answer thus far: how can you choose a different hit in the middle of the yank search movement?  eg say I have a buffer with the following contents:

```
1: foo bar

2: foo baz

3: This line contains the cursor.
```

Say I type `y?foo` in normal mode and realise that I don't want the foo in line 2 but its occurrence in line 1; is there a key I can press at this point to navigate between the different hits before choosing the one I need to complete the yank operation? (n and N don't apply as they change the search pattern)

This simple example does not do justice to the usual large buffer content I deal with and so I might not be able to see the search hits beforehand.  Also, at times I could make a mistake and realise that I want to find another occurrence in the middle of the operation.  Basically, I want to be able to lazily change course during the operation.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is interactive, use visual mode:

```
v?foo<cr>ny
```

Given your sample buffer above, this will search backwards for "foo", find another (backwards) match, and then yank all of the (visually-)selected text.

Visual-line mode is uppercase V and also often helpful.  Visual-block mode is ctrl-V and sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Mark your spot, search, and yank up to the mark:

```
ma
?foo
n
y`a
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I am actually looking for a way to change course in the middle of the operation without setting an explicit mark beforehand.

Comment: otherwise I could have used `y2?foo` :-)

Comment: Based on your reply, I thought I should add some further explanation to clarify what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could modify your regex so it only matches before a certain line:

```
y?foo\%<2l
```

I think it's just easier to use visual mode to make sure you are yanking exactly the right text:

```
v?foo<CR>y
```